# Full width background images

Tags: website-design, usability, gui-design, layout, fluid-layout

I want to allow users to upload full-width background images that would take up the entire width of the page (with a set height of 500 pixels). However, the issue is, what should be the minimum dimensions for the image that is to be uploaded?

I don't want people uploading tiny images that have to be stretched to ugly proportions to meet my needs of full-width backgrounds. So how can I find the sweet spot between required dimensions and user friendless of uploading?

Note: I am of course able to resize the uploaded images.

Comment: Your question is not really about UX. You should have more answers on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ or http://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the **[image guidelines](https://medium.com/help-center/652ee60abea6)** for Medium- which lists a minimum of 1200px and recommends 1400px. This falls in line with the statistics presented in sources like **[StatCounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/#resolution-ww-monthly-201303-201402-bar)** and **[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp)**. There's also interesting tidbits on how they scale and crop in order to support a responsive layout. Larger screens may be subjected to upscaled images with loss of detail. However, do note that screen resolution ≠ browser width and this is especially true with larger resolutions.